# data.table equivalent to mutate(case_when) conditions in multiple

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a dataset with multiples codes in 4 columns, I want to accomplish the same result as using the "mutate(case_when)" but with data.table or any other more efficient method, the real dataset has multiple codes that I need to mark if present in any other 4 dx columns and this method takes to long and extremely long commands.

```
id  dx1  dx2  dx3  dx4
1  1 5856 4543 5856 5856
2  2 6789 7737 4524 6737
3  3 4524 5856 4568 5856
4  4 2485 2457 5687 8457

#dataset
            id= 1:4
            dx1 = c(5856, 6789, 4524, 2485)
            dx2 = c(4543, 7737, 5856, 2457)
            dx3 = c(5856, 4524, 4568, 5687)
            dx4 = c(5856, 6737, 5856, 8457)
            df <- data.frame(cbind(id, dx1, dx2, dx3,dx4))
        
        df <- mutate(df, x = case_when(dx1 == 5856|dx2 ==5856|
                                   dx3 ==5856|dx4 ==5856|
                                   dx1 == 4524|dx2 ==4524|
                                     dx3 ==4524|dx4 ==4524
                                   ~ 1))


#mutate output 
      id  dx1  dx2  dx3  dx4  x
        1  1 5856 4543 5856 5856  1
        2  2 6789 7737 4524 6737  1
        3  3 4524 5856 4568 5856  1
        4  4 2485 2457 5687 8457 NA
```

Comment: ``df[ , x := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%in%`, c(5856, 4524))), .SDcols = patterns("^dx")]``

Comment: Henrik's suggestion is great! Slight adjustment would be to include `.SDcols = dx1:dx4`. Relevant to the question title, there is also `data.table::fcase()` which has similar but not identical syntax to `dplyr::case_when()`.